# Tempo entre (between) "tempo inicial" e "tempo fim"

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tendo problemas ao pegar o horário atual, no caso estou utilizando **CURTIME()**, preciso buscar os resultados que o horário atual, esteja entre o valor(tempo) da coluna **tempo inicial** e da **tempo final**, tentei das seguintes formas, porém, sem exito:

```
SELECT Programa.name, ProgramaHorario.horario_inicio, ProgramaHorario.horario_fim FROM programas as Programa
INNER JOIN programa_horarios as ProgramaHorario ON ProgramaHorario.programa_id = Programa.id
WHERE CURTIME() >= ProgramaHorario.horario_inicio AND CURTIME() <= ProgramaHorario.horario_fim
```

e

```
SELECT Programa.name, ProgramaHorario.horario_inicio, ProgramaHorario.horario_fim FROM programas as Programa
        INNER JOIN programa_horarios as ProgramaHorario ON ProgramaHorario.programa_id = Programa.id
        WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN ProgramaHorario.horario_inicio AND ProgramaHorario.horario_fim
```

É possível utilizar between? e o mais adequado para trabalhar com o tempo atual, é **CURTIME()** mesmo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Resumo da documentação do MySQL:

`CURRENT_DATE()` e `CURRENT_DATE` são sinônimos de `CURDATE()`

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE();        -> '2008-06-13'
mysql> SELECT CURDATE() + 0;    -> 20080613
```

`CURRENT_TIME()` e `CURRENT_TIME` são sinônimos de `CURTIME()`

```
mysql> SELECT CURTIME();        -> '23:50:26'
mysql> SELECT CURTIME() + 0;    -> 235026.000000
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` e `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` são sinônimos de `NOW()`

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();            -> '2007-12-15 23:50:26'
mysql> SELECT NOW() + 0;        -> 20071215235026.000000
```

O uso do `BETWEEN` é perfeitamente viável nestes casos, desde que os tipos das colunas sejam os mesmos. Em alguns casos, você pode usar um CAST, mesmo que implícito, desta forma:

```
-- implícito e numérico
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE CURTIME() + 0 BETWEEN hora1 + 0 AND hora2 + 0
-- explícito e horário apenas 
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN CAST( hora1 AS TIME ) AND CAST( hora2 AS TIME)
```

O cuidado que você precisa ter é quando misturar *timestamp* com apenas *time*. Neste caso, compensa extrair a parte necessária com as funçoes `TIME` ou `DATE` se quiser desconsiderar a data:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN TIME( dataHora1 ) AND TIME( dataHora2 )
```

> Cuidado quando se tratar de **casos em que o horário envolve dois dias diferentes** como entre 23h00 de hoje e 02h00 de amanhã, por exemplo. Veja a solução logo abaixo.

Há várias outras combinações possíveis de CAST e seleção da parte desejada, basta você isolar o que for mais conveniente para o seu caso.

### Aplicando ao caso prático:

Aqui temos uma query que aplica os conceitos acima, e que leva em conta tanto os horários no mesmo dia quanto em dois dias seguidos:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE
   ( CURTIME() BETWEEN LEAST( hora1, hora2 ) AND GREATEST( hora1, hora2 ) )
   XOR
   ( hora2 > hora1 )
```

Explicação: o `BETWEEN` vai retornar *true*, caso o horário esteja entre o menor dos horários e o maior (ordenados automaticamente pelo uso de `LEAST` e `GREATEST`). Entretanto, num caso em que a hora final é menor que a inicial, significa que queremos um número que **não esteja** nesta faixa, vide exemplo:

Se o horário inicial é 12h00 e o final é 14h00, e hora atual 13h00:

```
a condição   CURTIME() BETWEEN LEAST( hora1, hora2 ) AND GREATEST( hora1, hora2 )
equivale a   13:00:00 BETWEEN LEAST( 12:00:00, 14:00:00 ) AND GREATEST( 12:00:00, 14:00:00 )
equivale a   13:00:00 BETWEEN 12:00:00 AND 14:00:00
resulta em   true

a condição   hora1 > hora2
resulta em   false

a condição   true XOR false
resulta em   true
```

Entretanto, se o horário inicial é 23h00 e o final é 02h00, e o programa 01h00:

```
a condição   CURTIME() BETWEEN LEAST( hora1, hora2 ) AND GREATEST( hora1, hora2 )
equivale a   01:00:00 BETWEEN LEAST( 23:00:00, 02:00:00 ) AND GREATEST( 23:00:00, 02:00:00 )
equivale a   01:00:00 BETWEEN 02:00:00 AND 23:00:00
resulta em   false (deu false por que as horas estão invertidas, mas está dentro do horário)

a condição   hora1 > hora2
resulta em   true

a condição   false XOR true (aqui corrigimos a inversão das horas)
resulta em   true
```

Assim, com uma *query* relativamente simples, resolvemos todos os casos que envolvam até 24 horas, sem precisar usar datas.

Answer (score 1):

Agora deu certo, realmente a lógica estava errada. Conforme sugerido em um comment na resposta anterior, eu estava invertendo os valores do horários inicial e final.

```
SELECT Programa.name, ProgramaHorario.horario_inicio, ProgramaHorario.horario_fim FROM programas AS Programa
INNER JOIN programa_horarios as ProgramaHorario ON ProgramaHorario.programa_id = Programa.id
WHERE ProgramaHorario.horario_inicio >= CURTIME() AND ProgramaHorario.horario_fim <= CURTIME();
```

Comment: @Omni, não sei não, isto parece uma resposta sim. Helder, uma pequena explicação de qual é o problema ajudará futuros visitantes que tenham a mesma questão. Sua resposta veio parar na fila de Publicações de Baixa Qualidade por ser praticamente puro código.

Comment: @brasofilo concordo, se houver uma edição e explicar o que estava errado pode ser considerado resposta. Da forma que esta mais parece uma edição da pergunta.

Comment: Hmm, não entendi, o certo seria eu editar a pergunta inicial, e incluir a solução? Ou editar esta resposta para deixar mais clara? Sou iniciante com o stackoverflow, ainda me perco em algumas coisas.

Comment: @helderburato editei sua resposta para acrescentar os fatos relevantes dos nossos comments, mas sinta-se à vontade para modificar se necessário.

Comment: @Bacco obrigado!